# Python Function in Databricks

Tags: python, function, databricks

I am new to Databricks and Python, i am trying to write a function that checks if the values of a perticular column is present in a List of distinct value. Below is my code.

```
def dist_values_validatio(input_df,input_col,temp_df,temp_col):
    dist_Codes =   temp_df.select(temp_col).groupBy(f.lit("dummy")).agg(f.collect_set(temp_col).alias(temp_col)).first().asDict()
    dist_Value = dist_Codes[temp_col]
    ADT_Finalss = input_df.withColumn("Valid_check", f.when(~f.col(input_col).isin(dist_Value),1).otherwise(ADT_select.Valid_check))
```

then when i run the function(code below) it runs successfully but i cant get that df that i have defined in function.

```
dist_values_validatio(ADT_select,'eventTypeCode',Event_code,'value')
```

below is the error message when i try to display the df.

```
ADT_Finalss.display()
```

error message :
NameError: name 'ADT_Finalss' is not defined

please assist me finding the silly mistake that i am doing here

**note:**when i do it without function i am able to get the result , i can display the ADT_Finalss.display()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `ADT_Finalss` to be returned from the function when you call it, you have to add a `return` line to the function.

Also, when you call the function, you'll want to assign the return to a variable.

Example:

```
def dist_values_validatio(input_df,input_col,temp_df,temp_col):
    dist_Codes =   temp_df.select(temp_col).groupBy(f.lit("dummy")).agg(f.collect_set(temp_col).alias(temp_col)).first().asDict()
    dist_Value = dist_Codes[temp_col]
    ADT_Finalss = input_df.withColumn("Valid_check", f.when(~f.col(input_col).isin(dist_Value),1).otherwise(ADT_select.Valid_check)) 
    return ADT_Finalss

new_df = dist_values_validatio(ADT_select,'eventTypeCode',Event_code,'value')
```

Now `new_df` will have what you need in it.

Comment: Thanks Buddy.! , that worked , u r a champ :)